# vuejs router-link not working in lazy loading routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am setting my router follow this guide
https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html

```
const PageWaitingRoom= () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-CCManageBusiness" */'./../pages/customer-care/manage-business/PageWaitingRoom');
const Routes = [
  {
      path: '/customer-care/manage-business/waiting-room',
      component: PageWaitingRoom,
      name: PageWaitingRoom.name
   }
]
```

And in another page, I use router-link like this:

```
<router-link class="nav-link text-uppercase"
             :to="{name: 'PageWaitingRoom'}"
             exact>
        Waiting Room
</router-link>
```

Everything work fine until I use webpack to make production build with UglifyJsPlugin, the router-link not resolve the url, it always point to root url instead. I must change the router-link to not use the `name` like this:

```
<router-link class="nav-link text-uppercase"
             to="/customer-care/manage-business/waiting-room"
             exact>
      Waiting Room
</router-link>
```

But I don't want to do by that way, I refer to use component name in the router-link, since it is shortly and easy to me to change the url in the future.

This problem is only happen when I use UglifyJsPlugin, I am not sure what I am missing.
Anyone are facing this problem like me? Please give me advice.

Thanks!

Comment: This is maybe about `<base href="...">` or `output path` in webpack config file

Answer (score 0):

If you want you preferred version to work you need to disable mangling, like so:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  mangle: false
})
```

This should stop it messing with your route name but note that this also stops the obfuscation of the code. You can do a Google search to decide whether this is a problem or not. Some people say yes, others no.

I have disabled this option in my latest app with the reasoning that if someone is determined enough, renaming `PageWaitingRoom` to `xyz` isn't going to stop them, only slow them down.

Comment: Thank you webnoob, your answer makes me rethink about my code, where I used `Component.name` as the route name instead of a string for it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did not named the route by a string, but I used the `name` of the component as the route name instead, like below, and it makes my stupid poblem lol:

```
    const Routes = [
      {
          path: '/customer-care/manage-business/waiting-room',
          component: PageWaitingRoom,
          name: PageWaitingRoom.name //<-- UglifyJsPlugin will do its business and cause the route issue.
          //name: 'PageWaitingRoom' <-- Should use this
       }
    ]
```